# API in NextJS that serves a JSON file, can I edit this file (after build, while running) and make the API serve the updated file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Sorry for the wording in the question. Probably my biggest issue with this is not knowing how to phrase it correctly, as I've not been able to gleam a single hint of an answer from google.

Using api routes in Next.js I want to serve a `data.json` file. This works no problem, however I also want to be able to edit this file afterwards and for the api to reflect the updated content. As it stands after building and running if I edit the file the api still returns the old one, hell I can even delete it. I assume this is because Next.js makes a copy of the file at build time, and puts it somewhere in the .next directory(?), haven't been able to find it there though.

Below is a boiled down version of what I'm doing:

```
/pages
 /api
  /info.js

/data
  /data.json <- file I want to use with the api
```

`pages/api/info.js`

```js
export default function (req, res) {
  const data = require('../../data/data.json')
  // Do stuff
  res.status(200).json(data.something)
}
```

Any guidance on this is very appreciated

Comment: Is the issue updating the file while developing the project or for when the app is built and hosted somewhere?

Comment: @Matt it's when the app is built and hosted. I'm running it on a docker container and made a volume where this json file is in, i'd like to be able to edit the file and have the api  reflect the updated content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `require` to include a file in any Node app will definitely tie the json file to the apps run time or build time.

The feature you describe sounds like [static file serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) but next caches those files as well.

Try reading the file in the API instead

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises
export default async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const file_data = await fsp.readFile('../../data/data.json')
    const json_data = JSON.parse(file_data)
    // Do stuff
    res.status(200).json(data.something)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error reading data' })
  }
}
```

#### Actual Static files

In development you can probably work around this by triggering rebuilds when static files update.

If you want update the data files independently of a built app, they will probably need to be hosted separately to the Next build. If you are `next export`ing a completely static site, you might have a place to put the static files already. If not you can serve the data files with another [node process](https://github.com/koajs/static), or a [web server](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/), or something like [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html).

Comment: I have no issues when using `next dev` and running the app in development mode. My question is for when it's deployed. I don't want to just serve the entire file or anything, the API routing from nextjs would work perfectly if I can get it to read a file from somewhere nextjs won't cache it

Comment: I'm not sure how next treats regular files, maybe just try reading it? I've added an example

Comment: Brilliant that was it thank you very much! I had to use `path.join(process.cwd(), 'data/data.json')` as the path I passed into `fsp.readFile()` since it doesn't seem to accept just a relative path, and everything works as expected now. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Cool. `__dirname` might be more consistent as the prefix for this file, but can sometimes have differences between dev/built

Comment: I know this is a 2 years old problem, but there aren't a lot of stuff about this online. I have the same issue... I have no problem reading to the file, but I can't write to it. How did you fix this in the end? @DavidPH