# Change offline data in NextJS app without rebuild whole app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-deployment, vercel

I making NextJS app with static offline data using GetStaticProps.

The data comes from static array

```
export const data = [
  {
    title: 'Hey Mate1',
    subTitle:'How are you today?`,
    links: ['someLink, someLink'],

  },
  {
    title: 'Hey Mate2',
    subTitle:'How are you today?`,
    links: ['someLink, someLink'],
  }
]
```

I will use in future some services like Vercel

How can i in future update this data without rebuilding and deploying the whole app? For example i want change just data[0].title to 'Hello mate999999"

If i will use database, thats clear because of "revalidate: 10"
But im not sure about best practices with offline data in Next

Comment: You could try to put the data in a JSON file, then, on the backend, read this JSON file when making a request.

Comment: Thanks Haroldo for a advice, yeah i thought this will be some solutions. Put somewhere on server/ftp with static path and maybe this or put data on database will be one of solutions...

Comment: You may want to check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864564/api-in-nextjs-that-serves-a-json-file-can-i-edit-this-file-after-build-while

Comment: Why dont you use getSeverSideProps?